# Webscraping phonenumbers

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

First of all I'm a total newbie to programming and my English is not the best.

Im using Python 3.6 on Windows 10 Pro.

After some trial and error i finally figured out how to scrap data from a webpage via lxml and how to use beautifulsoup and csv to add it to an excel sheet.

So far that works out for me. It was pretty easy to collect lists of names, adresses and distance. But when i tried to extract the phone numbers and emails, i got in trouble. After some research i found out they split the phone number and kinda encoded it. Emails are also kinda tricky.

The webpage i want to extract that data from is:
https://www.gelbeseiten.de/schluesselfertigbau/bergheim,,,,,umkreis-50000

I found out that the first part of the phonenumber is in here:

```
<span class="nummer">(02271) 6 79</span>
```

They hided the rest in here:

```
<span class="suffix encode_me telSelector128028047679_2623072" data-telselector="telSelector128028047679_2623072" data-telsuffix="IDcw"> 70</span>
```

Even with the first part seems beeing easy, i cant use lxml how im used to for extracting it.

So my question is, if its still possible for a beginner to extract that phonenumbers and emails?

Or should i try to get those numbers out of the print PDF-files?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Are you asking if you can extract the digits from an HTML attribute? Sure. Give it a try and show us how it fails - we'll be happy to help!

Comment: Just to make this very clear, the full phonenumber should be `(02271) 6 79 70`?

Comment: @M.T. yes. thats the way i need it

Comment: It is even worse: the last part of the phone number is not present in the downloaded html: it is written with javascript after the download by DOM modification. That means that you cannot directly get it with just `urllib.request` and `BeautifulSoup`. Said differently, they do not want that you use their page from a bot...

Comment: hello Serge, is there any other way to do it? with: `import re
with open('text.txt') as fp:
          lines = fp.read().split("\n")` im getting a list from "strg-a" copied text which contains the full number. but i dont know how to filter that list for the phonenumbers. i tried regular expressions but i cannot deliver the needed pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution to get phone number:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

source = html.fromstring(requests.get("https://www.gelbeseiten.de/schluesselfertigbau/bergheim,,,,,umkreis-50000").text)
phone_number = "".join([text_node for text_node in source.xpath('//li[@class="phone"]//text()') if text_node.strip()])
print(phone_number)
```

*Output:*

```
'(02271) 6 79 70'
```

Comment: Or, a bit simpler with the `text_content`: `source.xpath('//li[@class="phone"]')[0].text_content().strip()`.

Comment: Yeap, I tried this also, but got `'(02271) 6 79\n\t\t\t\t 70'`.Maybe output looks like that only from my side as I didn't really test it with `requests`, but with HTML sample copied from browser dev tools...

Comment: thanks for that fast response. but my output looks slightly different: "(02271) 6 79(02181) 27 0(02161) 24 19(02131) 66 67(02103) 39 00(02173) 2 04 7(02235) 9 23 04(02232) 4 23(0157) 86 85 74(02181) 2 78 11(02181) 47 49 0(02202) 1 88(0211) 23 80(02235) 9 23 0" how do i seperate them into a list? and why is the suffix (e.g. 70) missing?

Comment: @DanielHe, As was already mentioned in comments the last digits comes from JavaScript and provided approach might work with static page only. You might need to use selenium to be able to handle dynamic content...